# How to access list in ViewModel from different ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I encountered some issue when I have some loaded a list from my logic and want to select some values from this list using a different viewModel.

```cs
public List<ContactsListModel> ExampleList
{
    get => _exampleList;
    set
    {
        _exampleList = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExampleList)));
    }
}
```

Above we have my list, which contains some data. I dont want to load it once again. How can I get values from it in a different viewModel?

Comment: Why are you using two view models in this scenario would be the better question? Do you have separate views? Please help us understand your issue better thanks

Comment: Yes, I have separate views,  2 Pages with two View Models, in one view model i have the list of values, then I want to get some info from this view model in other View model

Comment: Do you mean passing data to ViewModel while navigating?

Comment: I mean, get already loaded data to one ViewModel from another, but not while navigating. Imagine I have 2 Pages inside TabbedPage(maybe this is crucial), in one I have data, to which I need to have access from another page iniside Tabbed page to search some values in this particular list, Thank of your interest,             I am using MVVM so logic is done inside ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

I put things in a base class then inherit from base class, inheriting List.
I'm kind of new to Xamarin, So Not sure if this is recommended?

```
   public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => 
   DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

    bool isBusy = false;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of your view model to the page where you want to use it, from there you can access it.

1.
The Viewmodel you want to access:

```cs
Pushasync(new YourPage(this));  //Passed the instance of your view model
```

2.
The page where you want to access:

```cs
public partial class DemoClass
{
    YourViewModel demo_;

    public DemoClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DemoClass(Yourviewmodel demo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        demo_ = demo;  // access the instance and all its properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution with passing only the list ?

Comment: Just change the YourViewModel type of constructor argument to which ever Type you wish to pass. Any type can be passed. If your projects is going to get complicated. Use a MVVM framework like Prism, MVVMCross, etc..

Comment: Yes, @SzymonRożek you can pass the list, and use its declared data type on the page you want to access, as commented above

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be is to pass your view model instance to your view wherever required. However, the best way is to use any MVVM patters and register your instance using container.

Am using MVVM Light and there is a option there to use the SimpleIoc container there. Just register your ViewModels and get unique instances of your ViewModel anywhere require.

I have my ViewModels registered in a class called ViewModelLocator like below.

```
public LoginViewModel LoginVM
{
    get
    {
        if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<LoginViewModel>())
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        }
        return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And I have a property called Locator in my App.cs like below.

```
public static ViewModelLocator Locator
{
    get { return _locator ?? (_locator = new ViewModelLocator()); }
}
```

So anywhere required now, I can access the ViewModel as below.

```
App.Locator.LoginVM.[PropertyName] = [values to assign];
```

Comment: @Szymon: If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as an answer. Thanks...